# Image shadow in Internet explorer 6 and 7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I had heavily modified the canvas theme via child theme.

There is ugly border around the images in Internet explorer. Take look on the below screenshot and help me to resolve the same.

http://i51.tinypic.com/el1mp4.jpg

Please help me to troubleshoot this CSS issue.

Comment: I answered this in your other question. IE6 & IE7 have a very screwy implementation of CSS - use specific CSS for those browsers as shown in previous question and realise that you will not be able to achieve everything via CSS that you could with a CSS3 compliant browser. It's called graceful degradation

Answer (score 0):

[image: Image demonstrating artefacts in different browsers]

This is either a bug due to the VM being in 16bit colour or IE6's jpeg decompression techniques. Either way I don't think it's your website and I would advise you to just ignore the problem, stop worrying about IE6.

Comment: Thanks, the answer above should highlight the problem. Bear in mind that the issue you are highlighting is barely visible and I had to use photoshop before I even saw there was a problem.